# Using MakeMKV to view blu-ray in VLC

Tags: vlc, media, blu-ray

I have been trying to use MakeMKV to watch blu-rays in VLC. From what I've read, this should be possible using the libmmbd.so.0 library included with MakeMKV (https://www.makemkv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7009). I've created the link as directed in that post. However, when I run VLC and try to play a blu-ray, I get

```
aacs.c:546: Error calculating media key. Missing right processing key ?
[1]    19401 segmentation fault (core dumped)  vlc
```

Note that the MakeMKV has no issues reading or decrypting the same disc. If looking at the output of `dmesg`

```
28520.654358] vlc[19476]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f9f5bba6e06 sp 00007f9f742bc590 error 6 in libmmbd.so.0[7f9f5bb9f000+10000]
[28520.654364] Code: 89 e5 48 83 ec 30 48 89 7d e8 48 89 75 e0 48 89 55 d8 48 8b 45 e8 48 89 c7 e8 3a c5 ff ff 48 89 45 f8 48 8b 45 f8 48 8b 55 e0 <48> 89 10 48 8b 45 f8 48 8d 50 08 48 8b 45 d8 48 89 02 90 c9 c3 55
```

which looks to me like a segfault in the libmmbd.so.0 library. Any ideas on how to proceed?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, VLC 3.0.9.2, and MakeMKV 1.15.1.

Answer (score 0):

Where/how have you created the link? Is it definitely pointing to your copy of  libmmbd.so.0? Have you seen [this](https://www.makemkv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22307&p=91144&hilit=libmmbd#p91144) post which states:

> The instructions for adding libmmbd support are outdated/incomplete.
>
> The correct place to put the symlink on modern 64-bit Debian-based
> systems is in `/usr/lib/86_64-linux-gnu/`, not `/usr/lib`.

Comment: I created the link with `ln -s`, and it definitely points to the correct library: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jun 14 11:53 libmmbd.so.0 -> /snap/makemkv/198/usr/lib/libmmbd.so.0`.

I have tried putting the link in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, I still get a seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by compiling and installing MakeMKV from source: https://www.makemkv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=224

This installs the libmmbd.so library (as well as several others) directly in /usr/lib.

Not sure what was broken with the snap version.